# See if value exists and then get the value

Tags: php

So basicly, when a form is submitted on a comment and in the comment it contains `@username` or `@` then someone's username, I want to do something, e.g. send a notification to the username.

So, if it contains an `@` and a word (with letters or numbers) afterwards, I want to get the value and do something with it.

e.g.

```
if (contains an @ symbol, get the value of it)  {
// do something
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$str = 'hello @user';
preg_match('/@([a-z0-9]+)/i', $str, $matches);

// $matches[0] = '@user';
// $matches[1] = 'user';
```

Answer (score 0):

With this code you'll be able to check if the string contains '@'.

```
if(strpos('My @string', '@') !== false)
{
     //Actions if it found a @ in the string
}
else
{
     //Actions if it didn't found a @ in the string
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `\w` instead of `[a-z0-9]` you catch `_` characters, which are valid `user_names`.

```
$str = 'hello @user_name! Hello!';
preg_match('/@(\w+)/i', $str, $matches);
```